# Git error: Error: Could not fork child process: Resource temporarily unavailable (-1). DLL rebasing may be required; see 'rebaseall / rebase --help'

Tags: git, gitlab

1. Я использую gitlab, не github.
   Поэтому в директории `C:\Users\<имя_пользователя>\AppData\Local` нет папки GitHub.
2. Удаление и переустановка git не помогли.
3. Windows Defender и все его функции отключены.

Напсать в git ничего не даёт.

Есть варианты, как решить проблему?

[image: git-error]

Comment: windows vista?.

Comment: @KoVadim, Windows 7

Comment: пробуйте https://github.com/mintty/wsltty/issues/6 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399041/cygwin-update-cause-error-could-not-fork-child-process-resource-temporarily-u